# Minimum groups of contiguous sequences

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following problem which would be best described in a diagram:
consider the following sequences (can be any type of sequence: numbers, dates (in my case its dates), etc.)

[image: diagram]

I would like to find all the groups of the longest contiguous sequence like the output in the latter example, i.e. minimum amount of groups containing the longest sequence possible.

I thought of going with some sort of sorting/ordering (min/max doesn't seem to be much of a help here as I could have empty gaps), first by left point then by right, but I'm not sure about that either.

Comment: How is the data stored? I would figuratively flip the grid on it's side and iterate down through the list, checking if something is scheduled on that particular day.

Comment: @Joey Gennari - I can store the data however I want, in my case I have two lists of dates: start and end dates. I'm not sure how flipping it would help, it's not like each sequence in the latter diagram is a different date, I have overlapping dates there as you can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just spit-balling some pseudo-code from the last time I coded something like this:

```
var outputRanges = new List<Range>();
foreach (var range in inputRanges)
{
   // Let Range.Touches(Range) define a function that returns true
   // iff the two ranges overlap at all (that is, A.Start and/or A.End
   // is between B.Start and B.End)
   var overlaps = outputRanges.Where(range.Touches).ToList();

   // If there are no overlaps, then simply add it to the output
   if (!overlaps.Any())
   {
       outputRanges.Add(range);
   }
   // If there are overlaps, merge them
   else
   {
       outputRanges.RemoveAll(overlaps);
       overlaps.Add(range);
       outputRange.Add(new Range() {
           Start = overlaps.Min(_=>_.Start),
           End = overlaps.Max(_=>_.End)
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: This illustrates the exact solution (using somewhat similar algorithm as mcdowella's answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would sort start points and end points together into one sorted order and then process them in that order, keeping a running count of number of start points seen minus number of end points seen. When this counter drops to zero you have the start of a complete gap. Depending on whether abutting lines count as separated by a zero length gap or not you could sort start points before or after end points in the case of ties.

Comment: @msdowella - That was my initial hunch as well. Thanks for outlining the approach

Answer (score 0):

I don't have it in C# but did have to solve this exact problem in sql, perhaps this will give you a hint on how to turn this in to C#

```
select Resource_ID, Appointment_date, Min(NewStartTime) Start_Time, MAX(End_Time) End_Time
into #CleanedBlockTimes
from
(
    select *,
        NewStartTime = Dateadd(mi, v.number, t.Start_Time),
        NewStartTimeGroup =
            dateadd(mi,
                    1- DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Resource_ID, Appointment_date order by Dateadd(mi, v.number, t.Start_Time)),
                    Dateadd(mi, v.number, t.Start_Time))
    from #BlockTimes t
    inner join master..spt_values v
      on v.type='P' and v.number <= DATEDIFF(mi, Start_Time, End_Time)
) X
group by Resource_ID, Appointment_date, NewStartTimeGroup
order by Resource_ID, Appointment_date, Start_Time
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort on the start of the range.

Start at the head of the list, compare the end time with the start of the next item in the list.  If they overlap replace the end time with the max of the end time of the current record and the end time of the next record.  Remove the next record.  Repeat.

If there is no overlap advance to the next record and repeat.

O(n log n) for the sort, O(n) for the compile.  Overall, o(n log n).